# What is WoWEnabled?

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.6 on a 2017 Macbook Pro 15-inch.

When I run the airport utility `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport`, one of the given verbs is `prefs` which has some various preferences:

```
    DisconnectOnLogout (Boolean)
    JoinMode (String)
        Automatic
        Preferred
        Ranked
        Recent
        Strongest
    JoinModeFallback (String)
        Prompt
        JoinOpen
        KeepLooking
        DoNothing
    RememberRecentNetworks (Boolean)
    RequireAdmin (Boolean)
    RequireAdminIBSS (Boolean)
    RequireAdminNetworkChange (Boolean)
    RequireAdminPowerToggle (Boolean)
    WoWEnabled (Boolean)
```

Most of these are easy to guess or research online, but I can't find anything about the last one, `WoWEnabled`. I tried various searches involving `WoW`, which I guess to be "wifi over [something]" or "[something] over wifi", but include those in my queries also yielded nothing. There are very few github search results as well, none of which have any nearby comments or code that could be used to deduce its actual meaning.

If you run `airport prefs` (using the full path to airport as given above), you might find that `WoWEnabled=YES` or `WoWEnabled=NO`. Mine is YES but I saw snippets online for both values.

What does this mysterious preference mean??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WoWEnabled means "Wake for network access" which can be enabled and disabled in System Preferences > Energy Saver (> Power Adapter).

With WoWEnabled=No your Mac won't wake up if tickled.

Comment: What if I'm like really good at tickling?